# Display two div in same line or row

Tags: html, css

I want to display these two `div` in the same line.

Here my HTML code :

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col p-0 dossier-detail-btn" style="text-align: right;">
      <div style="display: inline-flex;width:100%">
         <button class="demo-button excercice-create-btn mdc-button font-Roboto-Medium mdc-button--raised mdc-ripple-upgraded" style="box-shadow: none;color: #0047FD;text-align:left;border: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 1px solid;background-color: white;margin: 0 10px;border-radius: 4px;" data-DebutActivite="@(doss.DateDebutActivite.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))" data-item="@(TnsHelper.Crypt (doss.Id.ToString ()))">
         CR&Eacute;ER UN EXERCICE
         </button>
      </div>
      <div style="display: inline-flex;">
         <div class="col-auto">
            <span style="vertical-align: middle;line-height: 1;font-size: 14px;color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);font-family: roboto-medium;" onclick="checkSupprimerDossier('@(Url.Action("Delete", "Dossier"))','@(Url.Action("CheckPwd", "Dossier"))','@(TnsHelper.Crypt (doss.Id.ToString ()))', '@(!string.IsNullOrEmpty (doss.PWDDossier) ? "true" : "false" )')">SUPPRIMER</span>
         </div>
         <div class="col-auto">
            <span style="vertical-align: middle;line-height: 1;font-size: 14px;color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);font-family: roboto-medium;" onclick="checkDupliquerDossier ('@(Url.Action("Dupliquer", "Dossier", new { idDossier = TnsHelper.Crypt (doss.Id.ToString ()) }))','@(Url.Action("CheckPwd", "Dossier"))','@(TnsHelper.Crypt (doss.Id.ToString ()))', '@(!string.IsNullOrEmpty (doss.PWDDossier) ? "true" : "false" )')">DUPLIQUER</span>
         </div>
         <button class="demo-button mdc-button mdc-button--raised mdc-ripple-upgraded" style="background-color:#0047FD !important;margin: 0 10px;border-radius: 4px;" onclick="checkOpenDossier ('@(Url.Action("Index2", "Exercice", new { idDossier = TnsHelper.Crypt (doss.Id.ToString ()) }))','@(Url.Action("CheckPwd", "Dossier"))','@(TnsHelper.Crypt (doss.Id.ToString ()))', '@(!string.IsNullOrEmpty (doss.PWDDossier) ? "true" : "false" )')">
         OUVRIR LE DOSSIER
         </button>
      </div>
      <div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you made one to be `width:100%`

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes without width it will be displayed right and i want it to be displayed left and for the other div i want it displayed right but both in the same line

Comment: and width:100% mean that it will be in the line alone, so it's not good

Comment: @TemaniAfif so what i do ? i have try with text-align

Comment: It looks like you're already using bootstrap flex grid, why not actually use it?

Comment: @ChrisW. yes i'am using bootstrap so how can i modify my code ?

Comment: @mecabpazzo95 as you use bootstrap, why not just use another row and two cols: https://www.bootply.com/svX1N0Cv1W

Comment: So you just want that "creer un exercice" button on the left, and the other two on the right with all of them on the same row? The whole point of using a UI framework like bootstrap is to help eliminate the bloat of inline styles and adhoc redundant code, so if my description of your goal is accurate we can help show you how to accomplish this much more cleanly.

Comment: @ChrisW. yes this is what i want exactly

Comment: @Pete i did it but it is not displayed good

Comment: probab ly because it means your second divs cols are no longer cols - remember with bs4, all cols should be wrapped in a row

Comment: Apply `d-flex` class to `.dossier-detail-btn` and they will display inline. You might also want to have a look at [Button Group](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/button-group/)

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu thank you problem solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I did strip off the inline styles and non bootstrap classes, but here's an example of how to accomplish what you're after. If I can offer any advice, it's to work on dropping the habit of working around what frameworks like bootstrap are for. Read [the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) and you'll quickly see how much effort and extra lines of bloat you could be saving just by learning how to use it.

Either way, hope this helps and happy holidays!

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col p-0">
    
      <button 
        data-DebutActivite="@(doss.DateDebutActivite.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"))"
        data-item="@(TnsHelper.Crypt (doss.Id.ToString ()))">
         CR&Eacute;ER UN EXERCICE
      </button>
    
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
    
      <span onclick="checkSupprimerDossier('@(Url.Action("Delete", "Dossier"))','@(Url.Action("CheckPwd", "Dossier"))','@(TnsHelper.Crypt (doss.Id.ToString ()))', '@(!string.IsNullOrEmpty (doss.PWDDossier) ? "true" : "false" )')">
      SUPPRIMER
      </span>
      
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto">
    
      <span onclick="checkDupliquerDossier ('@(Url.Action("Dupliquer", "Dossier", new { idDossier = TnsHelper.Crypt (doss.Id.ToString ()) }))','@(Url.Action("CheckPwd", "Dossier"))','@(TnsHelper.Crypt (doss.Id.ToString ()))', '@(!string.IsNullOrEmpty (doss.PWDDossier) ? "true" : "false" )')">
        DUPLIQUER
      </span>
    
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto p-0">
    
      <button 
        onclick="checkOpenDossier ('@(Url.Action("Index2", "Exercice", new { idDossier = TnsHelper.Crypt (doss.Id.ToString ()) }))','@(Url.Action("CheckPwd", "Dossier"))','@(TnsHelper.Crypt (doss.Id.ToString ()))', '@(!string.IsNullOrEmpty (doss.PWDDossier) ? "true" : "false" )')">
         OUVRIR LE DOSSIER
      </button>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```